# In multicolumn text, stick div to the bottom

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to stick a div to the bottom of a column in CSS3 multicolumn text.

Obviously

> position:absolute, bottom:0

breaks column. Is there any way to achieve this effect? Or maybe there is more efficient way to organize multicolumn text?

```css
.col {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}

.bottom {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to
    using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>


  <p>Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

  <p class="bottom">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
    from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
</p>
```

Update:

Ok, thank you so much for answers, but seems like I'm not very clear:

[image: Please, have a look at yellow block]

So yellow block is the one which is stuck at the bottom of second column and this is something I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Stick to bottom how? .. full width of parent, or in one of the columns, or ...?

Comment: Inside one of the columns, here is an example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2b70lbi1avt3sm7/blocks.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS column, and without script, there is only one way to dynamically make this work, and that is to duplicate the `.bottom` item, hide one and absolute position the other.

The hidden one is needed to make sure its content's size is taken into account when calculating the total size of the column's height, or else the positioned one will overlap the previous content.

```css
.col {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;     /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #777;  
}

.bottom-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #777;  
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to
    using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>


  <p>Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

  <p class="bottom-hidden">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
    from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>

  <p class="bottom">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
    from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>

</div>
```

---

If the size of the text is somewhat known, another possible option would be to give the second last column item a bottom margin, matching the last items height, though this fixed height needs to be well tested on different screen sizes, so it doesn't overlap.

```css
.col {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;     /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}

.col *:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% + 10px);       /*  Safari needed this  */
  width: calc(50% - 20px);      /*  Safari needed this  */
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #777;  
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to
    using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>


  <p>Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

  <p class="bottom">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
    from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Both of examples do not work in Safari. But better then nothing, thanks. I think I like the idea with margin.

Comment: @Mee How does it not work in Safari? .... Does this work: https://jsfiddle.net/oxjLnukh/

Comment: @Mee Updated my answer with that change

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `p` tag outside of the `.col` div. Is this what you need?

```css
.col {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}

.bottom {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to
    using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>


  <p>Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
</div>

<p class="bottom">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not something that I want to do. I updated question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}

.bottom {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to
    using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
    infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>


  <p>Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>


</div>


<p class="bottom">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
  from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
```

You have closed `div` tag just before `p` tag.

I have changed your example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not something that I want to do. I updated question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

This, kind of, can be done (and with usage, as you thought in the beginning, `position: absolute`): https://jsfiddle.net/y1kethst/

Bear in mind that it will produce text-over-text result if the column in which `.bottom` element is in is not smaller of two.

```css
.col {
      -webkit-column-count: 2;
      /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -moz-column-count: 2;
      /* Firefox */
      column-count: 2;
      border: 1px solid #ff0;
      position: relative;
    }

    .bottom {
      border: 1px solid #777;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    
    p {
overflow: hidden; /* Fix for firefox and IE 10-11  */
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
break-inside: avoid-column;}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="col">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
        has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

      <p>Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to
        using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
        infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>


      <p>Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
        in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
        of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
        from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

      <p class="bottom">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
        from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
</div>
Additional content
</div>
```

Comment: This only works because of the items is almost equal in size. Double the text size in the first item and it breaks.

Comment: So - double the text amount. As I've written in my answer - `Bear in mind that it will produce text-over-text result if the column in which .bottom element is in is not smaller of two.`

Comment: @Mee I think at this point it's better to consider `flex` column layout as `columns` support looks indeed dodgy

Comment: @eithed can you show me an example of building same layout with flex? My problem is this section is user-generated, so I can't predict length of the content, except for "bottom" block.